# Javascript innerHTML with session PHP from other page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have 2 page

- the innerhtml onclick page   (a.php)
- the page that start session   (b.php)

in a.php  I write function onclick to change some text 
and I add the session from b.php in this text, but nothing change in text

```
 $(document).ready(function(){       
      $('.add-to-cart').on('click',function(){

        document.getElementById('outside_cart_text').innerHTML = 
"Qty type <?php echo $this->session->userdata('qty_type'); ?> amount <?php echo $this->session->userdata('qty_product');?>";

            });
        });
```

it change the original text to "Qty type amount". But session value not appear.

the question is how to make it appear instantly?

additional detail : My click is on the button sumbit to other page, but I have already use this trick. It work like ajax. so after click I still in the same page (and not reload)

```
<style>
  .hide { position:absolute; top:-1px; left:-1px; width:1px; height:1px; }
</style>

<iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hide"></iframe>

<form action="receiver.pl" method="post" target="hiddenFrame">
  <input name="signed" type="checkbox">
  <input value="Save" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Where session variables get initialized?

Comment: b.php page  <?php  
$this->session->set_userdata('qty_type', sizeof($this->cart->contents()));
$this->session->set_userdata('qty_product', $this->cart->total_items());
?>

Comment: Do you have session_start in a.php?

Comment: yes  I use framework  that auto start session every page

Comment: the  button in a.php will submit to b.php page  and the update qty's logic is in the b.php page too.

Comment: Can you try var_dump($_SESSION); outside the js code of a.php and paste it here?

Comment: If you are using `codeigniter`,you using `controller` to declare `session variables`?

Comment: Hi!  I create new thread here  with more detail  please come :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231791/session-php-with-ajax-innerhtml-shopping-carts-quantity-order

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would work if the variables are encoded in json format.

```
document.getElementById('outside_cart_text').innerHTML = 
  "Qty type
  <?php echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('qty_type')); ?> 
  amount 
  <?php echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('qty_product'));?>";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click',function(){
        var qty_type = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('qty_type'); ?>';
        var amount = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('qty_product'); ?>';
        $("#outside_cart_text").html("Qty type "+qty_type+" amount "+amount);
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry session value don't come

Comment: you would have to call session value using ajax from b.php and then add into html

Comment: Can you give example ajax code for this situation? :) I don't know .ajax .post .get which one I should use.